# What's the best practice accessing $_GET values in Laravel?

Tags: parameters, laravel

Is there a better way in accessing `$_GET` rather than the variable itself in Laravel or is that it?

I need multiple parameters for an API like `/users?q=keyword&order=desc&limit=5`

Is there a cleaner, safer and Laravel-ish way to access the $_GET values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Input` facade to reach those.

You can either do:

```
Input::all();
```

to retrieve all of the query parameters, or:

```
$q     = Input::get('q'); // will return 'keyword' for your example
$order = Input::get('order'); // will return 'desc' for your example
$limit = Input::get('limit'); // will return '5' for your example
```

Comment: Purely FYI: `Input::get()` will retrieve both $_GET and $_POST variables.

Comment: Input::query shall be used to access only $_GET values.

Comment: Note: The "get" method is used for all request types (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE), not just GET requests.