# Can't retrieve url GET parameters with Laravel 5.1on remote server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

For some reason I can't get any GET parameters from a url in my controllers using the `Illuminate\Http\Request` facade. I tested in multiple controllers, but no success.

Using the following code, nothing is returned on the remote server when accessing `domain.com/admin/dashboard?test=test`, but on my local machine it returns `test`:

```
The dashboard function is called by the route /admin/dashboard

/**
 * Dashboard page
 *
 * @return  view
 */
public function dashboard(Request $request)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($request->all());
    echo '</pre>';

    // Return here
    return;

    // ...instead of here
    return view('backend::pages.dashboard');
}
```

I'm running Laravel 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Nginx and php5-fpm. The code works fine on my local Homestead instance as well as on MAMP. I checked my Nginx configuration and everything seems fine. I'm hosting multiple sites on my server and I can get route parameters on all other sites.

Comment: Facing the same problem. Did you get any proper solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If anyone runs into this, the problem was with how I set up Nginx for this particular domain.

This block in my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file didn't work with query strings:

```
location / {
    try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
}
```

After changing it to the following, everything worked as it supposed to be:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me

Comment: I need location exactly, please. I to have the same problem

Comment: @srinivas location of what?

Comment: 5 years on and your post is still of great help

Answer (score 1):

Try to access it like this:

```
$var = Input::get('test');
```

Here is how to do it: [Retrieving GET and POST data inside controller in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761555/retrieving-get-and-post-data-inside-controller-in-laravel-4)
And also here: [What's the best practice accessing $_GET values in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759665/whats-the-best-practice-accessing-get-values-in-laravel)

Hope helps

Comment: I've tried this before but it doesn't work either since Input::get just maps to Request::get

Comment: Hmmm, and what is output of `Input::all()`?

Comment: Also, try this: `$segment = Request::segment(3);`

Comment: The same as $request->all() in my controller

Comment: i dont need a segment from the url.

Comment: Yeah, but you can get from this part of the url $_GET parametrs I think.

Comment: Anyway, its strange, because as is written for example there: [http://daylerees.com/codebright-request-data/](http://daylerees.com/codebright-request-data/) you are doing it right...

Comment: Yeah it really is strange, the only thing I can think of is that my Nginx isn't set up properly but I checked it a hundred times and it's all right. Other sites on the server work properly.