# query string not working in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Once I'm redirect url from facebook oauth url  not getting query string in laravel 5.1.

URL look like this : [http://www.karconnect.com/account/facebook?code=AQBt8A0zZlCM-viDYLZmpqeOJcvgZb5en1LoK22vvnSXXCgFqQNyqQUWY7DxbxhSLnlAdDTrFbjkzFbgCb3--rN77a88AUmo3AdVG9FR3h-4NCR60xgnvglsT_FpNj-HaEU-0xPFsxrVYYdi2-PO9wP74GEBnlIWZe52ZNTdhsU-4AMZJ7W7F9Anpu_ZCR3YuyCxNmOIqpPwFMx1oD52x4dppCb38J1Fu7l9hvm4hQTiba0B8eP0MCZ_69t4H_9mtqX0fvEpeRR1PKn0T16VtrIbz_2u4dl3EwiabbsEcJLQ-w6m_26NulkvWsj0D34oE3wMusK7aMSwNDtK1SdOzxy_&state=QnrpWtaYBLYnaxKb3IR0R9Wg7UGg0UrooCS4g0P4#*=*](http://www.karconnect.com/account/facebook?code=AQBt8A0zZlCM-viDYLZmpqeOJcvgZb5en1LoK22vvnSXXCgFqQNyqQUWY7DxbxhSLnlAdDTrFbjkzFbgCb3--rN77a88AUmo3AdVG9FR3h-4NCR60xgnvglsT_FpNj-HaEU-0xPFsxrVYYdi2-PO9wP74GEBnlIWZe52ZNTdhsU-4AMZJ7W7F9Anpu_ZCR3YuyCxNmOIqpPwFMx1oD52x4dppCb38J1Fu7l9hvm4hQTiba0B8eP0MCZ_69t4H_9mtqX0fvEpeRR1PKn0T16VtrIbz_2u4dl3EwiabbsEcJLQ-w6m_26NulkvWsj0D34oE3wMusK7aMSwNDtK1SdOzxy_&state=QnrpWtaYBLYnaxKb3IR0R9Wg7UGg0UrooCS4g0P4#_=_)

Once I print `print_r($_GET);` nothing getting anything.

please help for same, why it's not working.

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of SO questions about this. You need to use the input request, not the superglobal. Here's one exampel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759665/whats-the-best-practice-accessing-get-values-in-laravel

Comment: Thanks you for reply, but once I written www.yoururl.com/index.php/xyz?test=test at a time i will get value of  test ? any configuration i did missed ?

Comment: faced same problem. Any hints @HIteshTank

Answer (score 1):

As Joel Hinz has mentioned, you should be using the `Input` facade to do this.

If you want to retrieve it all then you can use `Input::all();`.

Otherwise you can retrieve the individual inputs like so:

```
$code = Input::get('code');
$state = Input::get('state');
```